# Are return-to-libc attacks possible now?

Tags: linux, security, buffer-overflow

I'v read that to make a successful return to lib-c attack, the attacker should store the address of the command (for example "bin/sh") on the stack exactly after the return address to 'system' function (for example).

So as the 'system()' function reads that address as its 'parameter' and executes that command. But now after disassembling a program which calls system() I noticed that it doesn't use the stack to get the address of that string ("bin/sh"). Instead the address is stored in EDI or RDI registers. As long as the attacker can't access the registers how is it possible to perform such an attack?

Comment: Providing a specific example of what you are talking about perhaps using [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) to demonstrate it live as well, would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It might actually be easy for an attacker to have the correct value stored in `RDI` without having direct access to the registers.

Take a typical vulnerable C function that might lead to a return-to-libc attack:

```c
void f(const char* str)
{
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    strcpy(buf, str);
}
```

On my machine, the following assembly is generated for the call to `strcpy`:

```c
movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rdx, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    strcpy
```

As you can see, the destination buffer of `strcpy`, which is the vulnerable buffer, is stored in `RDI`. This means that if we manage to overwrite the return address with the address of `system`, it will be called with a pointer to the vulnerable buffer as its argument.

A small disclaimer: this particular example is just to illustrate that having the correct value in a register can be accomplished by other ways than having direct access to the register. The example itself is actually very difficult to exploit since `strcpy` will stop after the first null byte.

Comment: Thanks but I think I should clarify the situation. The problem is not the value in RDI itself. It's the memory location in which the attacker must store the buffer. for example suppose that I as the attacker know the value that is stored in RDI is '0x400430' which doesn't point to the buffer but instead to something like a general variable. If I want the system() executes what I want I have to write to address '0x400430' which is somehow impossible because it's too far from the current position of stack frame and I can't deliver 1Gb characters to input.

Comment: @user2808671: What I tried to show is that in a typical vulnerable function, where `strcpy` is used to inject a payload, `RDI` has the correct value just after the call to `strcpy`. This means that *if* you can find a vulnerable call to `strcpy` closely followed by a return, you *may* be able to exploit it.

Comment: Yes you're right. strcpy / memcpy / use EDI/RDI.  But besides using it, they change the value of RDI while copying the the data. with each byte copied, RDI is incremented by one. so RDI after returning from gets()/memspy()/strcpy() is pointing to the 'end' of buffer. The attacker needs it to point to the beginning or at least to a position before the string command "bin/sh". right?

Comment: @user2808671: Yes, you're completely right. Again, I just meant to show how you *might* get a correct value in a register. The specifics will have to be worked out for each concrete case.